# Printing values in device in GPU without lanching kernel

Tags: cuda

I have copied data from CPU to GPU:

```
 cudaMemcpy(d_signal, h_signal, sizeof(int) *1024, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Now I want to check whether correct data is reached inside device memory or not. Is it possible to do this without launching a kernel and also without explicit GPU-CPU copying? If yes, how?

Comment: This is a very strange question. Are you really asking "if the cudaMemcpy API doesn't return an error message, did it really work?" or something else?

Comment: @talonmies you are absolutely correct. Actually I just wanted to make sure that data has been copied 100% correctly. I do not want to check by explicit copying back from device to host, as I have hude amounth of data.

Comment: A debugger is always a good idea for these kinds of checks, why not use one?

Comment: I still don't understand why you think this is necessary. You have several API calls which can tell you exactly when the copy is finished and that the copy was executed without an error. Why do you think is it then necessary to check values after a copy?

Comment: If the memcpy returns no err, but your program still has problem, you may want to focus on other part of your code rather than doubting about the correctness of the mem transfer.

Answer (score 1):

How about copy the data back from the device to host and then print them out?

```
cudaMemcpy(h_signal_out, d_signal, sizeof(int) *1024, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

copy(d_signal_out, d_signal_out+1024, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));
std::cout<<std::endl;
```

Comment: Your idea is correct, but as I have a huge amount of data which I do not want to do CPU-GPU and then GPU-CPU transfer.

Comment: @gpuguy Compared to the time for "print"ing the data one by one to some human readable place, time for mem transfer can be ignored. Then the Q becomes how do you define your "check", which takes much shorter time than mem transfer? Maybe using some checksum value is an option.